# Changing the number of View Controllers affected by Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a navigation controller that is at the beginning of a series of view controllers.  The series consists of 5 view controllers, but I want the navigation controller to only use the first 4 view controllers.  Im not sure if there is a way to change the relationship between view controller 4 and view controller 5 so that view controller 5 and the rest of the app are not affected by the navigation controller.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not affected by NavigationController?

Comment: The flow that you want is kind of confusing... so the user can go forward & backwards between the 1st - 4th viewcontrollers, but if he gets at the 5th one he gets stuck there? Could you provide a real example so we can suggest the best solution?

Comment: seems like you are asking on ViewController 5 you  do not want to get the default nav bar created by Navigation controller

Comment: If you don't want to show the navigation bar on fifth viewcontroller you can set the property self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false and on other 4 view controller you can set it to true. and can call in viewwillappear()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im not sure if there is a way to change the relationship between view controller 4 and view controller 5 so that view controller 5 and the rest of the app are not affected by the navigation controller.

There are a number of things that you *could* do:

- **Remove the navigation controller** entirely and make your "view controller 5" the window's root view controller.
- **Set the navigation controller's array of view controllers** to an array that contains only "view controller 5." This would effectively make that view controller the navigation controller's root controller, and from there you could just never push another controller onto the navigation stack.
- **Keep the current relationship,** but hide the navigation bar and prevent the user from going back to "view controller 4."
- **Rethink your user interface.** For example, if your first four view controllers are meant to lead the user through some set of initial questions, a login procedure, etc., then you could make "view controller 5" the app's main view controller, and present the navigation controller containing the controllers 1-4 modally.

Of those, and without knowing what you're actually up to, I believe reconsidering your UI is probably the best plan. Users should generally be in control of your app instead of the other way around, and they should never wonder why they can't get back to some part of the app that they've seen before. Also, it's poor form to break behaviors that users have learned to expect, and changing the user's ability to navigate through a series of view controllers would be a prime example. Using a modal presentation of the navigation controller with the first four view controllers should be fine, though.

Comment: Sorry I should've provided a bit more content.  So the section of the app I mentioned is a part where a user would sign up for an account.  So view controller (VC) 5 is a confirmation screen that takes the user back to the main page.  I agree from what you said that rethinking the user interface option would be the best.  However, I am not sure how I would present the nav controller modally.  If there was any way you could help with that, that would be amazing!

Comment: Disregard my last comment.  I was able to use the storyboard to use an action segue and present it modally.  Thank you for your help!